# How to marshall a LPCWSTR to String in C#?

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

I'm trying to define a P/Invoke signature for the following method (defined in `propsys.h`)

```
PSSTDAPI PSRegisterPropertySchema(
    __in PCWSTR pszPath);
```

I've seen on the `WinNT.h` that `PCWSTR` is an alias to `LPCWSTR` as

```
typedef __nullterminated CONST WCHAR *LPCWSTR, *PCWSTR;
```

And the `PSSTDAPI` is an alias for `HRESULT`

So how should be the P/Invoke signature for the `PSRegisterPropertySchema` method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After set the `CharSet` value to `CharSet.Unicode` it worked.

```
[DllImport("Propsys.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
static internal extern int PSRegisterPropertySchema(String pszPath);
```

Without specifing the CharSet the function was returning `0x80070057` which is  `E_INVALIDARG`.